# What did it mean to hand over a cat drawing in "Holmes and Watson"?

Tags: plot-explanation, holmes-and-watson

In [*Holmes and Watson* (2018)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holmes_%26_Watson),  **Millie** hands over a drawing of a cat to Sherlock to which he reacts as if it was an insult.

I cannot figure out what it actually meant.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: intended as insulting word pussy may be?

Comment: @Vishwa: That makes sense. Please add that as answer.

Answer (score 4):

Millie, who is Holmes love interest, is the aide and research subject of Dr. Grace Hart. When she first meets Holmes and Watson she is introduced by Dr. Hart with the following:

> Millicent is the subject of my research.
>   She was raised by feral cats. She has the mental capacity of a four-year-old, but it is my belief that with sufficient electroshock therapy, she can achieve the intellect of a six-year-old.

The scene you ask about occurs just after Holmes has accused Dr. Watson of being the mastermind behind a plot to kill the queen. Watson has been dragged off to jail and is to be executed. Dr. Grace Hart confronts Holmes who dismisses her concerns. Dr. Hart states that in America Dr. Watson would have gotten a trial before his execution and she storms off.

Holmes turns to Millie and says;

> Millie, surely you must understand.

Millie who has not spoken throughout the movie hands Holmes a picture of a sad kitty. This is to represent her disapproval of the way Holmes has treated Watson. She then storms out.